# Emergence of Lognormal distribution for the concentration of chemical compounds

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, reference-request, central-limit-theorem

I'm currently reviewing the literature about lognormal distributions describing/approximating the variability of a given chemical compound across different cells/ samples etc etc.

The main argument pro lognormality is the multiplicative central limit theorem, that many authors mention without providing a clear example of a reaction pathway where a targeted concentration can be approximated by the multiplication of many factors. In [this article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5036630) and [that](http://web.mit.edu/jakebeal/www/Publications/ENB17-Lognormal-Biology.pdf) they make the case of autocatalytic/ catalytic processes.

What would be the simplest example of a chemical reaction system where the concentration of a target chemical (not the rate) would appear Lognormal?